# How to use saved template (from a subsite) in the parent root site?

Tags: web-template

I have a sharepoint 2010 portal. The site collection is create by the site template "publishing site". I have created a sub site. I have enabled some features to create the (calendar, announcements, links and tasks) lists. I created 4 lists (calendar, announcements, links and tasks). After this added these 4 lists on my homepage in some zones.

At this point I would like to save this site as a template. At the first moment I didnt find the "save as template" link in site settings. After some google search, I found you need to deactive the publish feature. I did deactivate this publish feature. The link "save as template" was visible.

I saved this site as a template. Everything is OK. If I create a new site I can see my saved template. But if I go to the parent site, and try to create a new site, I dont see my saved template!

How can I use my saved template in the subsite at the parent site (root site)?

Answer (score 1):

Saving publishing enabled sites as a template is not supported and it does not work. Even if you deactivate the publishing feature or manually type in the URL to go to the /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx page of the site, you will still run into problems because publishing sites are depended on some content and references that are generated when the feature is activated. It is recommened that you create a custom site definition instead. This post (http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=144) might lead you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

you need to deactivate the "SharePoint Server Publishing" at the root site(parent site).After this you will be able to see your saved template .

Comment: But the root site still needs to be a publishing site. This is one of the requirements of the root site. What to do now?